# namespaces - composer cannot load classes when moved into src directory

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am preparing php library and decided to reorganize directory structure a bit.
Everything was working and from this structure:

[image: This was working]

I decided to move into:

[image]

I regenerated autoload (php composer.phar dumpautoload), ran tests and got:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Compa\Components\Finder\Objects' not found in /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/tests/Finder/ObjectsTest.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:65
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:346
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:769
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:824
PHP  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:969
PHP  13. Compa\Components\Test\Finder\ObjectsTest->find() /home/mrok/php/top/pac-b-test/tests/Finder/ObjectsTest.php:0
```

autload_namespaces contains:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/yaml/',
    'Compa\\Components' => $baseDir . '/src/',
);
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Should I change include path? I do not think so, otherwise everyone who use this library will have to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it valid [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), your file should be located in:

```
src/Compa/Components/Finder/Objects.php
```

but no idea why it was working with previous structure...